# Error Building CSipSimple for Android

Tags: android, csip-simple

I am trying to build CSipSimple application for android. I followed all instructions in https://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/wiki/HowToBuild. I also installed all packages too, but I am getting following error while executing the 'make' command on CSipSimple directory.

```
Mac-mini:CSipSimple-master sino$ make -no-check-certificate
(make -n -C jni/silk init)
wget --no-check-certificate https://developer.skype.com/silk/SILK_SDK_SRC_v1.0.9.zip; \
    unzip -d  sources -q SILK_SDK_SRC_v1.0.9.zip; \
    rm SILK_SDK_SRC_v1.0.9.zip
# Needed for 1.0.8 // todo test
#@mv sources/SILK_SDK_SRC_v1.0.9/* sources/
# source checkout done
# Init done
(make -n -C jni/opus init)
# old uri : https://git.xiph.org/opus.git
git clone git://git.opus-codec.org/opus.git sources; \
    cd sources; \
    git fetch --tags; \
    git checkout origin; \
    git checkout v1.1
# Init done
(make -n -C jni/zrtp4pj init)
git clone git://github.com/r3gis3r/ZRTP4PJ.git sources; \
    cd sources; \
    git fetch --tags; git checkout origin; git checkout  V3.2.0_4; \
    cd zsrtp; \
    git clone git://github.com/r3gis3r/ZRTPCPP.git zrtp; \
    cd zrtp; \
    git fetch --tags; git checkout origin; git checkout  V3.2.0;
# Init done
(make -n -C jni/openssl init)
git clone https://github.com/android/platform_external_openssl.git sources; \
    cd sources; \
    git fetch --tags; \
    git checkout origin; \
    git checkout fa610339baf67da107ba040930352c974b38256f
# Init done
(make -n -C jni/libvpx init)
git clone https://code.google.com/p/webm.libvpx sources; \
    cd sources; \
    git fetch --tags; \
    git checkout origin; \
    git checkout v1.1.0;
quilt push -a && \
    touch .patched_sources
mkdir -p build/armeabi
cd build/armeabi; \
    if [ "build/armeabi/config.mk" = "build/armeabi/config.mk" ]; then TGT=armv5te-android-gcc; fi; \
    if [ "build/armeabi-v7a/config.mk" = "build/armeabi/config.mk" ]; then TGT=armv7-android-gcc; fi; \
    if [ "build/x86/config.mk" = "build/armeabi/config.mk" ]; then TGT=x86-android-gcc; fi; \
    if [ "build/mips/config.mk" = "build/armeabi/config.mk" ]; then TGT=mips32-android-gcc; fi; \
    BUILD_PFX=jni/libvpx/build/armeabi/ ../../sources/configure --target=$TGT --disable-examples --sdk-path=/Users/sino/Documents/android-ndk-r9d
mkdir -p build/armeabi-v7a
cd build/armeabi-v7a; \
    if [ "build/armeabi/config.mk" = "build/armeabi-v7a/config.mk" ]; then TGT=armv5te-android-gcc; fi; \
    if [ "build/armeabi-v7a/config.mk" = "build/armeabi-v7a/config.mk" ]; then TGT=armv7-android-gcc; fi; \
    if [ "build/x86/config.mk" = "build/armeabi-v7a/config.mk" ]; then TGT=x86-android-gcc; fi; \
    if [ "build/mips/config.mk" = "build/armeabi-v7a/config.mk" ]; then TGT=mips32-android-gcc; fi; \
    BUILD_PFX=jni/libvpx/build/armeabi-v7a/ ../../sources/configure --target=$TGT --disable-examples --sdk-path=/Users/sino/Documents/android-ndk-r9d
mkdir -p build/x86
cd build/x86; \
    if [ "build/armeabi/config.mk" = "build/x86/config.mk" ]; then TGT=armv5te-android-gcc; fi; \
    if [ "build/armeabi-v7a/config.mk" = "build/x86/config.mk" ]; then TGT=armv7-android-gcc; fi; \
    if [ "build/x86/config.mk" = "build/x86/config.mk" ]; then TGT=x86-android-gcc; fi; \
    if [ "build/mips/config.mk" = "build/x86/config.mk" ]; then TGT=mips32-android-gcc; fi; \
    BUILD_PFX=jni/libvpx/build/x86/ ../../sources/configure --target=$TGT --disable-examples --sdk-path=/Users/sino/Documents/android-ndk-r9d
mkdir -p build/mips
cd build/mips; \
    if [ "build/armeabi/config.mk" = "build/mips/config.mk" ]; then TGT=armv5te-android-gcc; fi; \
    if [ "build/armeabi-v7a/config.mk" = "build/mips/config.mk" ]; then TGT=armv7-android-gcc; fi; \
    if [ "build/x86/config.mk" = "build/mips/config.mk" ]; then TGT=x86-android-gcc; fi; \
    if [ "build/mips/config.mk" = "build/mips/config.mk" ]; then TGT=mips32-android-gcc; fi; \
    BUILD_PFX=jni/libvpx/build/mips/ ../../sources/configure --target=$TGT --disable-examples --sdk-path=/Users/sino/Documents/android-ndk-r9d
# Preconfigure for each done
(make -n -C jni/fdk_aac init)
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/aac sources; \
    cd sources; \
    git fetch --tags; \
    git checkout origin; \
    git checkout jb-release
# Init done
(make -n -C jni/pjsip patch)
quilt push -a && \
    touch .patched_sources
# Patch done
(make -n -C jni/webrtc patch)
quilt push -a && \
    touch .patched_sources
# Patch done
(make -n -C jni/ffmpeg patch)
quilt push -a && \
    touch .patched_sources
# Patch done
(make -n -C jni/libvpx patch)
quilt push -a && \
    touch .patched_sources
# Patch done
(make -n -C jni/silk patch)
quilt push -a && \
    touch .patched_sources
# Patch done
(make -n -C jni/fdk_aac patch)
git clone https://android.googlesource.com/platform/external/aac sources; \
    cd sources; \
    git fetch --tags; \
    git checkout origin; \
    git checkout jb-release
quilt push -a && \
    touch .patched_sources
# Patch done
# External sources fetched out from external repos/zip
(make -n -C jni/webrtc preprocess)
make[1]: *** No rule to make target `sources/build/generate_asm_header.py', needed by `sources/modules/audio_processing/aecm/aecm_core_neon_offsets.h'.  Stop.
make: *** [webrtc-preprocess] Error 2
```

Answer (score 4):

This problem is related to the SILK package. The source URL of SILK is moved to a different one. You have to download it from the source and install manually to continue. 
Steps to be followed :-

1. svn checkout http://csipsimple.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/ CSipSimple-trunk (when successful, don't make)
2. Download  SILK_SDK_SRC_v1.0.9.zip: http://code.google.com/p/bkvoice/downloads/detail?name=SILK_SDK_SRC_v1.0.9.zip&can=2&q=
3. Create folder sources in /jni/silk/
4. Unzip and copy to sources
5. cd CSipSimple-trunk/CSipSimple
6. make

Comment: It was a long time back. But yes, I could build.